# Baking on a rocket stove

Tags: baking, equipment, stove

I'm wondering if it is possible to bake on a [SilverFire rocket stove](http://www.silverfire.us/silverfire-survivor-rocket-stove), ie. by attaching a metal box to the top, or any other way? I have researched it- Google search, YouTube etc, but can't find any relevant info.

Comment: You must not have tried very hard, research-wize: Try "rocket pizza oven" or just "rocket oven" for your search term, and we'll see you in a couple of months.  http://www.woodfiredpizza.org/rocket-oven-construction.html and https://youtu.be/h4WDZMmkDeo

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't think of phrases to search. Though I'm looking for ways to utilise my current stove, which I probably should have mentioned is a silverfire stove, and these are about making one.